# Relabeling/Keeping in Prometheus

Tags: regex, prometheus, monitoring

**Setup**

```
  - job_name: "tse"
    http_sd_configs:
      - url: "http://tse.mydomain.url/something"
        basic_auth:
          username: "foo"
          password: "bar"
    metric_relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__param_fccid]
        regex: (.*)
        target_label: fccid
        replacement: ${1}
```

**Issue**

In Prometheus, I see that the endpoint is scraped, and the endpoint contains the `fccid` parameter. But the parameter is not written/kept as label.
I'm trying different things since yesterday (labelkeep, keep, replace, labelmap, relabel_configs) and nothing worked.

Is the `metric_relabel_configs` not working for `http_sd_configs`?

Comment: Have you tried `__meta_fccid` rather than `__param_fccid`?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas: I tried. No change. In the "Targets"-Page of prometheus in the coloumn "Labels" the parameter is written as `"__param_fccid"="12"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer. I had to use `relabel_configs` instead of `metric_relabel_configs`.

Thank you @Michael Hausenblas . I was trying first known parameters and configs (internet) to adopt it.